# Apache Storm - spout and bolts not present in Storm UI

Tags: apache-storm, apache-kafka

I am developing a storm topology locally. I am using the Storm 0.9.2-incubating and have developed a simple Topology. When I deploy it using the LocalCluster() option, it works fine, but it will not show up in my Storm UI it just executes.

When I deploy it regularly, it will show the Topology in my Storm UI, but no spouts or bolts will be visible when I click it.

I have also tried this with example WordCountTopology that comes in many storm starter projects. The same behavior happens.

My question is really, why are the spouts and bolts not showing up? If you deploy a topology locally without using LocalCluser() option will that cause problems? Is it possible to deploy a topology on my local box and see it in Storm UI with all the spouts and bolts and not have it execute immediately, but wait for something such as a kafka message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running Storm Supervisor? If you deploy a new topology and Supervisor isn't running the topology will show up in the UI but since its never initialized it doesn't show any stats when you click into it.

Comment: Yep that was the problem.