# Apache storm ui does not show bolts and spouts

Tags: apache, user-interface, apache-storm

I am running Apache Storm topology in local mode, it works fine, but when I submit it to storm, the spouts an bolts does not show up in the Storm UI, except the topology.

It was suggested that the Supervisor should be running and I have tried that also, i.e. Supervisor, nimbus and zookeeper are running fine. Thanks in advance. Similar question is asked which suggests that Supervisor should be ON [Apache Storm - spout and bolts not present in Storm UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28631697/apache-storm-spout-and-bolts-not-present-in-storm-ui)
... but that does not work in my case any idea, please.

```
 /usr/local/storm$ jps
721 RemoteMavenServer36
6017 Supervisor
5780 Nimbus
6181 UIServer
5672 QuorumPeerMain
489 Main
7499 Jps
4927 Launcher
```

Comment: Could you list out the commands you use to run your topology, including how you start Storm itself?

Comment: Yes, of course:
`zookeeper/bin$ zkServer.sh start` 
`/storm$ bin/storm nimbus`
`/storm$ bin/storm supervisor`
`/storm$ bin/storm ui`

I have also tried running above commands in different orders... but same thing happens.. **@StigRohdeDøssing thanks, your help is appreciated.**

Comment: These commands are fine. Which command are you using to submit your topology?

Comment: I have used this command `bin/storm jar /usr/local/ADMIExampleForStorm/examples/storm-example/target/storm-example-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar admicloud.storm.wordcount.WordCountTopology WordCount` and topology is submitted successfully and also topology is visible at the UI but when I click on the topology there is no details of bolts and spouts.And I have tried 2 or 3 different topology having bolts and spouts but no luck.

Comment: Ok. Most likely there is something wrong with the jar you're submitting, or something is preventing your workers from starting. Check the logs in the storm/logs/workers-artifacts directory, and see if there are any errors being logged.

Comment: worker.log.err shows these logs: `[0.000s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:artifacts/gc.log instead.
Unrecognized VM option 'PrintGCDateStamps'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`

Comment: And worder.yaml file has this entry: `worker-id: 9c541d3a-6133-4426-aa00-e37a29056d34
logs.users: [null]
logs.groups: []
topology.submitter.user: GHAWSI`

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are using a version of Storm that has some JVM arguments set by default, which aren't compatible with Java 9+. You need to replace the arguments by modifying the `worker.childopts` setting in your `conf/storm.yaml`.

The settings you want to use will be something like

```
worker.childopts: "-Xmx%HEAP-MEM%m -Xlog:gc*:artifacts/gc.log:time,uptime:filecount=10,filesize=1M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=artifacts/heapdump"
```

Comment: Still not able to see the details for spouts and bolts in the UI and got this log in worker.log.err `Unrecognized VM option 'PrintGCDateStamps'
[0.000s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:artifacts/gc.log instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`

Comment: What are the contents of your conf/storm.yaml?